# Kelly's Proof Of Reconstruction Conjecture For Trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

The vertex reconstruction conjecture states that a graph on n>2 vertices can be discovered from only knowing its proper induced subgraphs.

Kelly proved this for trees in 1961. I saw his proof and I was asking the question: is his original proof still the only or simplest out there?

Comment: One warning: the reconstruction problem is very slippery, and "knowing its proper induced subgraphs" is ambiguous. If $G$ has $n$ vertices, then for each isomorphism class of graphs on $n-1$ vertices you are given the number of vertices $v$ such that the 1-vertex-deleted subgraph $G\setminus v$ lies in this isomorphism class. (And I don't think there has been any significant improvement to Kelly's argument.)

Comment: Right you are, I meant "multiset" rather than set. I gather that's still an open problem (when you are allowed the set but not the multiset).

Comment: Yes, I believe both versions of the problem are still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found this survey by Bondy and Hemminger: "Graph Reconstruction: A Survey", where they give a significantly smaller proof on trees using a "Counting Lemma" generalising "Kelly's Lemma".

Comment: Wow great answer John, thankyou very much. I'd love to uprate it, but for some reason I can't... damn it!